# Complex collection filter with lodash

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

I have a nested JSON structure along the lines of:

```
[
  {
    name: 'some name',
    type: 'type1',
    collection: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  },
  {
    name: 'another name',
    type: 'type1',
    collection: ['one', 'two']
  },
  {
    name: 'third name',
    type: 'type2',
    collection: ['two']
  }
]
```

I'm trying to write a lodash _.filter statement (as simple as possible), where I could filter on string properties like type, but also filter on an array property like collection checking if it includes certain values. e.g., I'd like to find all the objects that have a `type` of `type1` and have a `collection` array that contains the values `one` and `two`.

Is there a shorthand for this type of thing, or am I stuck writing a function that does some `typeof` gymnastics to determine the property value type, and then compare accordingly?

Comment: [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#filter) has a shorthand for that using `_.matches` if you provide an object as the predicate. The documentation has everything needed to answer if something exists or not in the library.

Comment: the subject isn't really that *complex*

Comment: I mean 'complex' in that it's a nested data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`_.matches`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#matches) shorthand of [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#filter) to perform partial deep comparisons as you filter:

```js
var array = [{"name":"some name","type":"type1","collection":["one","two","three"]},{"name":"another name","type":"type1","collection":["one","two"]},{"name":"third name","type":"type2","collection":["two"]}];
    
var filtered = _.filter(array, { 
  type: 'type1', 
  collection: ['one', 'two'] 
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh man, do I feel stupid. I swear I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this. it's simple enough.

```
_.filter(arr, item => {
    const hasCollection = item.collection && item.collection.indexOf('one') > -1 && item.collection.indexOf('two') > -1;
    return item.type === 'type1' && hasCollection;
});
```